# How to use variable into password_hash second argument?

Tags: php, constants, password-hash

I'm trying to hash a password using `password_hash()` by passing in the hash algorithm name using a string:

```
$password = '121@121';
$hash_method = 'PASSWORD_BCRYPT';
$password_encrypted = password_hash($password, $hash_method);
```

However, this results in a warning:

> Warning: password_hash() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given

If I would like to dynamically determine the algorithm, e.g. from configuration variable set in the database, how can I pass a string value to `password_hash()`?

Comment: `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` is a constant not a string. No need for the quotes

Comment: fine, but how can I get it from a database, for example?

Comment: I think the question is why do you have a constant name saved in the database?

Comment: @DawidWalczyk What do you mean by this comment you left? *"how can I get it from a database, for example?"*.

Comment: If you store such data in the database, why not use `constant($variable)` for that?

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` is a [constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php) - not a string. PASSWORD_BCRYPT is a human-friendly version of a numeric value - it saves on having to remember a billion numbers and their corresponding values.

**Edited info**

Dharman found [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.incompatible.php#migration74.incompatible.core.password-algorithm-constants) - indicating that from PHP7.4 the const values for the encryption types, will no longer be numeric values.

Password hashing algorithm identifiers are now nullable strings rather than integers.

```
PASSWORD_DEFAULT was int 1; now is NULL
PASSWORD_BCRYPT was int 1; now is string '2y'
PASSWORD_ARGON2I was int 2; now is string 'argon2i'
PASSWORD_ARGON2ID was int 3; now is string 'argon2id'
```

Simply remove the quotes and it's good-to-go:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    $password = '121@121';
    $hash_method = PASSWORD_BCRYPT;
    $password_encrypted = password_hash($password, $hash_method);

    echo '<pre>'. print_r($password_encrypted, 1) .'</pre>';
```

If, you're getting `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` from `$_POST` or a database, you can use the `constant()` function:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    $password = '121@121';
    $hash_method = 'PASSWORD_BCRYPT';
    $password_encrypted = password_hash($password, constant($hash_method));

    echo '<pre>'. print_r($password_encrypted, 1) .'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`constant()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function.

```
password_hash($password, constant($hash_method));
```

`constant()` takes in string as an argument and returns the value of the constant of the same name. It should be used together with [`defined()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) to make sure that such constant exists and you don't get a warning.

For example:

```
$algorithm_value = defined($hash_method) ? constant($hash_method) : PASSWORD_DEFAULT;
$password_encrypted = password_hash($password, $algorithm_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the second parameter `$algo` of `password_hash` with a [password algorithm constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php) `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` not the string `'PASSWORD_BCRYPT'`

```
/**
 * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.5.0, PHP 5)<br/>
 *
 * Creates a password hash.
 * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php
 * @param string $password The user's password.
 * @param int $algo A <a href="http://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php" class="link">password algorithm constant</a>  denoting the algorithm to use when hashing the password.
 * @param array $options [optional] <p> An associative array containing options. See the <a href="http://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php" class="link">password algorithm constants</a> for documentation on the supported options for each algorithm.
 * If omitted, a random salt will be created and the default cost will be used.
 * <b>Warning<b>
 * <p>
 * The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now
 * preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default.
 * </p>
 * @return string|bool Returns the hashed password, or FALSE on failure.
 * @since 5.5.0
 */
function password_hash ($password, $algo, $options = null) {}
```